# Проблема с получением данных API

Tags: php

Столкнулся с проблемой - на выделенном сервере код не получает данные от Steam API, в то время как на локальном сервере код работает идеально.

Собственно, непосредственно код:

```
$url = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=$apiKey&steamids=$matches[1]";
$json_object= file_get_contents($url);
$json_decoded = json_decode($json_object);
foreach ($json_decoded->response->players as $player)
{
    $PlayerName = $player->personaname;
    $ProfileUrl = $player->profileurl;
    $Avatar = $player->avatarfull;
}
```

Comment: Очевидно, что на сервере запрещены такие функции, а-ля `file_get_contents` или может даже `curl`. Не обговаривали это с поддержкой хоста?

Comment: Дедик на Debian, лично проверял, включен ли allow_url_fopen - включен. Тем более, буквально в соседней директории лежит набросок веб-приложения, использующий все тот же file_get_contents для получения данных с api вконтакте - и код работает

Comment: а что в `$json_object` приходит? Пустой совсем? А если включить отображение всех ошибок - что нибудь выводит?

Comment: Вывод ошибок включен - пусто. В $json_object ничего не приходит вообще - https так-же пробовал

Comment: Там на стиме какой нибудь привязки вызывающего api к ip и т.п. нет ? А то это выглядит как будто они отфильтровали и отдали пустой ответ. Если у вас дедик то наверное консоль есть, попробуйте из консоли по этому URL пойти, curl или wget или еще чем нибудь таким

Comment: Пробую аналогичный запрос в браузере проводить - работает. Уже даже не представляю, в чем может быть проблема, оттого тему и создал